# Highcharts formats differently in Safari vs Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, highcharts, safari

I am using the following code which produces the desired Highchart formatting that I want in Safari. However when I tried it in Google Chrome I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: this.value.slice is not a function" even when I don't change anything.

In the xAxis section I change the string read in from the csv file from something like this '02/15/2016 10:31:46' to '10:31:46'.

However when I remove the entire xAxis section in the below code and run it in Chrome, it automatically formats the xAxis to be something like '10:31'. Personally I would prefer the format that is produced when the below code is used in Safari. I was just wondering does anyone know why this happens or what is it in Chrome that changes the way the below code works.

```
$.get(data, function(csv) {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      zoomType: 'x',
      type: 'column',
    },
    data: {
      csv: csv,
      lineDelimiter: "\n",
    },
    title: {
          text: 'CSV file data'
      },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Bytes'
        }
    },
    xAxis: {
      labels: {
        //Only show the time (not date and time)
        formatter: function() {
              return this.value.slice(10,-4);
        }
      } 
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            marker: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }
    }
  }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `value` is not a String, then Chrome will not find `.slice()` - TypeError is thrown.

This is because Chrome is successful with parsing your date format into JavaScritp timestamp.

One way could be to set type of xAxis to `'category'`, because I guess this is what you are using.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/vs6qpobq/

Another way is to make sure that date is parsed correctly in Safari by adding a paring function in [`parseDate`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#data.parseDate) and get an info from a timestamp.

Comment: Adding category to the xAxis section fixed this issue, Thank you!